# Rendering a label doesn't work unless the screen function evaluates to it

Tags: clojure, play-clj

I'm trying to `render!` a simple label on the `on-render` screen function, but it doesn't work. All I get is a blank screen.

It took me some time but I finally found that this happens when I return something else but the label. For example, this works:

```
(defscreen main-screen
  :on-show
  (fn [screen entities]
    (update! screen :renderer (stage))
    [])

  :on-render
  (fn [screen _]
    (clear!)
    (render! screen [(label "Hello, world!" (color :white))])))
```

This doesn't (all that's changed is the last line on `on-render`):

```
(defscreen main-screen
  :on-show
  (fn [screen entities]
    (update! screen :renderer (stage))
    [])

  :on-render
  (fn [screen _]
    (clear!)
    (render! screen [(label "Hello, world!" (color :white))])
    ["I just wanna pass my own data here, ugh.."]))
```

For testing, I replaced the `label` with `texture` and *it did* work.

What's causing this? it seems so arbitrary (the label I evaluate to in the first example gets completely ignored anyway! so why do I have to pass it? I don't get what's going on).

P.S. creating the label on every frame is intentional in this case, and I know I could just set it from one I make in `on-show`, but I tried to be a bit more dynamic. I also tried to put a `Thread/sleep` after `render!` to make sure I have a visible time-window between rendering & clearing.

I'm a complete beginner I'd like to know why the above doesn't work in addition to how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

checkout the play-clj's [defscreen-doc](http://oakes.github.io/play-clj/#core.defscreen.html) , in particular:

> All functions take a screen map and entities vector as arguments, and
>   **return the entities list** at the end with any desired changes. If a
>   function **returns nil**, the entities list is not changed.

You neither return `nil` nor the (optionally changed) `entities`, but a vector with a string.

I expect that is the reason for the non-functioning code - haven't tested it though.

What is your intention with your "own data"?

Comment: The entities I'm trying to have is a vector with one element which is a map of my game's state. I wanted to make a label with text from the state and `render!` it. This is how I've done it for my `clear!` color and my textures' drawing, and everything is rendered except that label.